# AngularJS frontend for OSGi backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, osgi

I'm having problems structuring a frontend with AngularJS. I have a backend based on OSGi, a plugin based architecture with Java. Every plugin/bundle in OSGi, has a lifecycle: INSTALLED->RESOLVED->STARTED->STOPPING->STOPPED->UNINSTALLED, etc.
I am able to handle this in the backend without problems.
Now, in the frontend I'm building an application with a main module with AngularJS. That module should depend on all others, but as you see, these dependencies are dynamic. A few modules could be available, while others not. Some modules could be started after the application has bootstrapped or stopped.
I can't achieve this kind of dynamism with Angular so far, because once the main module has bootstrapped it can not add/remove new dependencies in real time.
Angular separates the routes, controllers, directives, factories, etc among modules through dependencies.
How should I solve this?
Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind providing a simplified example of what you are trying to achieve? I mean an example of couple of modules, how they relate to what you call "main module" and how you expect the Angular app to behave as those change their states.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant to you, but you can create a bundle for rest endpoints and allow your OSGi environment to manage the dynamic nature of your system so the frontend doesn't have to handle it.